# How do I extract links from HTML using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract links from google.com; My HTML code looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/" class="l"
```

I took me around five minutes to find a regex that works using www.rubular.com.
It is:

```
"(.*?)" class="l"
```

The code is:

```
require "open-uri"
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby"

source = open(url).read()
links = source.scan(/"(.*?)" class="l"/) 

links.each { |link| puts #{link} 
}
```

The problem is, is it not outputting the websites links.

Answer (score 4):

Those links actually have `class=l` not `class="l"`.  By the way, to figure this put I added some logging to the method so that you can see the output at various stages and debug it.  I searched for the string you were expecting to find and didn't find it, which is why your regex failed.  So I looked for the right string you actually wanted and changed the regex accordingly.  Debugging skills are handy.

```
require "open-uri"
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby"

source = open(url).read

puts "--- PAGE SOURCE ---"
puts source

links = source.scan(/<a.+?href="(.+?)".+?class=l/)

puts "--- FOUND THIS MANY LINKS ---"
puts links.size

puts "--- PRINTING LINKS ---"
links.each do |link|
  puts "- #{link}"
end
```

I also improved your regex.  You are looking for some text that starts with the opening of an a tag (`<a`), then some characters of some sort that you dont care about (`.+?`), an href attribute (`href="`), the contents of the href attribute that you want to capture (`(.+?)`), some spaces or other attributes (`.+?`), and lastly the class attrubute (`class=l`).

I have `.+?` in three places there.  the `.` means any character, the `+` means there must be one or more of the things right before it, and the `?` means that the `.+` should try to match as short a string as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To put it bluntly, the problem is that you're using regexes. The problem is that HTML is what is known as a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_free_language), while regular expressions can only the class of languages that are known as [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

What you should do is send the page data to a parser that can handle HTML code, such as Hpricot, and then walk the parse tree you get from the parser.

Answer (score 0):

> What im going wrong?

You're trying to parse HTML with regex. Don't do that. Regular expressions cannot cover the range of syntax allowed even by valid XHTML, let alone real-world tag soup. Use an HTML parser library such as Hpricot.

FWIW, when I fetch ‘http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby’ I do not receive ‘class="l"’ anywhere in the returned markup. Perhaps it depends on which local Google you are using and/or whether you are logged in or otherwise have a Google cookie. (Your script, like me, would not.)

Comment: Well, yeah.  That too.  HTML parsers are much better at this.